# react native firebase - onNotification callback is not triggered when app is in foreground Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am receiving message from fcm and firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened is working fine while app in background but firebase.notifications().onNotification is not triggered when app in foreground

**Androidmanifest.xml:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.knowledgeupdateapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.knowledgeupdateapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.knowledgeupdateapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
          android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="<Removed APIkey>"/>


      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name"
                android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL NAME"/>
      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description"
                    android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL DESCRIPTION"/>
      <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@android:color/white"/>


      <receiver
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
      android:exported="true"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <category android:name="com.knowledgeupdateapp" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>

    <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerServiceGcm" android:exported="false" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
    android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
          android:exported="false" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

 <!-- Background Messages (Optional) -->

  <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  DrawerLayoutAndroid,
} from 'react-native';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import DropdownAlert from 'react-native-dropdownalert';


import reducer from './app/Redux/reducers';
import { setNavigator, setActiveRoute } from "./app/Redux/actions";
import DrawerContent from './app/Navigation/DrawerContent';
import Toolbar from './app/Navigation/Toolbar';
import AppNavigation from './app/Navigation/AppNavigation';
import { bgStatusBar, bgDrawer } from './app/global.styles';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

let store = createStore(reducer);
/* getDrawerWidth       Default drawer width is screen width - header width
* https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html
*/
const getDrawerWidth = () => Dimensions.get('window').width - (Platform.OS === 'android' ? 56 : 64);

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.drawer = React.createRef();
    this.navigator = React.createRef();
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(setNavigator(this.navigator.current));

    //this will get initial notification
    // when can we use this: this can be use if app running in background at that time
    // we receive notification, during on tap of notification we will get data
    const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
    console.log("--", notificationOpen)
    if (notificationOpen) {
      const action = notificationOpen.action;
      const notification = notificationOpen.notification;
      var seen = [];
      // if you send custom data in additional option you can access those data like below
      alert(JSON.stringify(notification.data, function(key, val) {
          if (val != null && typeof val == "object") {
              if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
                  return;
              }
              seen.push(val);
          }
          return val;
      }));
    }
    const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel('test-channel', 'Test Channel', firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max)
                .setDescription('My apps test channel');

    // Create the channel
    firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

    this.notificationDisplayedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationDisplayed((notification) => {
        // Process your notification as required
        // ANDROID: Remote notifications do not contain the channel ID. You will have to specify this manually if you'd like to re-display the notification.
        console.log("invoked display listener")
    });

    this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
      // Process your notification as required
      console.log("invoked onnotification listener")

      notification
          .android.setChannelId('test-channel')
      firebase.notifications()
          .displayNotification(notification);

    });

    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
      console.log("invoked notification open")
        // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
        const action = notificationOpen.action;
        // Get information about the notification that was opened
        const notification = notificationOpen.notification;
        var seen = [];
        alert(JSON.stringify(notification.data, function(key, val) {
            if (val != null && typeof val == "object") {
                if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
                    return;
                }
                seen.push(val);
            }
            return val;
        }));
        firebase.notifications().removeDeliveredNotification(notification.notificationId);
    });

    this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
      // Process your message as required
      console.log("message listener")
    });
  } 

  componentWillUnmount() {
      this.notificationDisplayedListener();
      this.notificationOpenedListener();
      this.notificationListener();
  }



  openDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer.current.openDrawer();
  };

  closeDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer.current.closeDrawer();
  }; 

  getActiveRouteName = navigationState => {
    if (!navigationState) {
      return null;
    }
    const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
    // dive into nested navigators
    if (route.routes) {
      return getActiveRouteName(route);
    }
    return route.routeName;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Provider store={store}> 
          <DrawerLayoutAndroid
            drawerWidth={getDrawerWidth()}
            drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
            renderNavigationView={
              () => <DrawerContent closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer} />
            }
            drawerBackgroundColor={bgDrawer}
            ref={this.drawer}
          >
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <StatusBar
                  translucent
                  backgroundColor={bgStatusBar}
                  animated
              />
              <Toolbar showMenu={this.openDrawer} />
              <AppNavigation
                onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
                  const currentScreen = this.getActiveRouteName(currentState);
                  store.dispatch(setActiveRoute(currentScreen));
                }}
                ref={this.navigator}
              />
            </View>
          </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
        </Provider>
        {/* common notification component */}
        <DropdownAlert ref={ref => global.dropDownAlertRef = ref}  closeInterval={2000} tapToCloseEnabled={true} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is fixed by below changes. I am using react-native-push-noticiation and aslo react-native-firebase I just changed my Androidmanifest.xml. Moved my react-native-firebase service code before react-native-push-notification service like below

```
<!-- first react-native-firebase  -->
     <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

 <!-- Background Messages (Optional) -->

  <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />

 <!-- next react-native-push-notification  -->
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>

    <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerServiceGcm" android:exported="false" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
    android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
          android:exported="false" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Now my onNotification get trigged and also onNotificationOpen working fine.

For more details view - https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1518#issuecomment-530653657